# Do rebuild of only necessary jars with Maven

Tags: java, maven, build

Is it possible to have all maven rebuild all modules that depend on a given module `A`?  That is, including modules that have modules that depend on `A`, etc. all the way up the dependency tree?

I know I can do something like this
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144568/force-recompilation-of-war-file-including-its-jar-dependencies
to manually get this going.  However this becomes cumbersome when working with any real code.  If you have hundreds of modules with lots of dependencies you really don't want to make a pom for each set of different combinations.  And you don't want to have a super pom because that will just take forever to build.

The algorithm would be fairly basic.  If module `A` changes just look for where something depends on it, then rebuild that as well.  Repeat with the just built modules until no more modules are left.  Does this functionality exist in maven without have to create a new pom?

EDIT: I meant when dealing with snapshots. Thanks @StackFlowed

Comment: **DONT RELEASE A NEW JAR WITH SAME VERSION** its a horrible solution. I know a way in pom you can point it to another pom version. You can make the change in all your module to point to that pom and then going forward you will just have to change the parent pom version.

Comment: You should take a look at `mvn -pl ModuleYouWouldLikeBuild -amd` should do what you like. `-amd` stands for `also make dependencies`...

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you post your comment as an answer?  It completely answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at

```
mvn -pl ModuleYouWouldLikeBuild -amd
```

should do what you like. -amd stands for also make dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You can use the also make dependents reactor option.
http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/

See the above link for some nicely documented examples.