# Maven only compile changed sources

Tags: java, git, maven

I have a multi-maven project with a couple of bundles inside.

```
pom.xml
|
bundles
\- bundle1--pom.xml
\- bundle2--pom.xml
testproject
\- bundle1--pom.xml
```

When building `mvn package` is there a way to just recompile bundles that contain changes? E.g. I only change something in `bundle1`, so maven actually only needs to recompile this and dependent bundles. What maven does is to recompile every bundle.

I thought maybe there could be a way to detect git changes or similar, so there might be way to do this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you could use `-pl` option to specify a module you want, but if you want it to be dynamic, you have to combine this with some scripting (shell or something else) to detected recent modified files

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918165/does-maven-support-incremental-builds ... though it is not the same question.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416277/do-rebuild-of-only-necessary-jars-with-maven